# Bootstrap Modal - catch link click inside modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to catch a "click on a link" inside a bootstrap modal, but for some reason it is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu-mobile a').click(function() {
    alert();
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="menu" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="menu-mobile">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Menu</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="button xsmall" id="closeForm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to wait until the document is loaded, use [`$(document).ready(function(){your code ....});`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: I did, but I should have added this to the code. Adjusting it.

Comment: double id in class="modal fade"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use event delegation `.on()` like :

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '#menu-mobile a', function() {
        alert();
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** You should remove one of the id's in your modal since you've two now `id="menu" & id="menu-mobile"`.

Comment: When i use this, I don't get an alert.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki you detected the prob +1 to morocco :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have id attribute twice on your modal element:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="menu" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="menu-mobile">
```

assuming you'll change it to

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="menu-mobile">
```

then to access even dynamically generated content within the modal, run:

```
$('#menu-mobile').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    alert();
});
```